# What is the role of the xmlns attributes in RDF?

Tags: xml, rdf, xml-namespaces

I am new to RDF and I am trying to get some RDF files from the web. For example:

http://rdf.freebase.com/rdf/venture_capital.views.investment_round

or

http://sws.geonames.org/2950159/about.rdf

The problem is, that I should add a few xmlns attributes to the  tag, but I don't know which nor why.
Also, should I add a xml header or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use  tags you need to declare the RDF namespace

```
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
```

likewise for any of your own namespaces. All XML files should have an XML header.

E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:myns="http://my.domain/schema#"
>
   <myns:something rdf:about="http://my.domain/data/item.1">
      <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://my.domain/schema/thing"/>
      <myns:property1>Value</myns:property1>
   </myns:something>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: thank you, but where do I get the attributes like 'xmlns:myns="http://my.domain/schema#" ' from?

Comment: @Dragos, for your own data you define the namespaces and their URI:s. Important to notice is that namespace URI:s are identifiers, not URLs for accessing content. So, they are up to you.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the role of the xmlns attributes in RDF?

They let you distinguish `<foo>` from namespace a from `<foo>` from namespace b (where it might be something subtly different … or completely different.

> The problem is, that I should add a few xmlns attributes to the tag, but I don't know which nor why.

It is rather had to know "why" or "which" without knowing the other (or at least "on what"). Why do you think you need to add them if you don't know what or why?

> Also, should I add a xml header or not?

Define "xml header". If you mean the XML declaration of `<?xml ... ?>` then you only need that if you aren't using the defaults (UTF-8/16 and XML 1.0)

Comment: I have the two links above and I want to create RDF files on my computer. The problem is, that the <gn> or <fb> tags aren't recognized by my parsers. Where should I get the xmlns from? (Obviously, they aren't any specifications on the pages above.)

Comment: From the files you referenced: `xmlns:gn="http://www.geonames.org/ontology#"` and `xmlns:fb="http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/"`

Comment: I now understand what you just did... Thanks.